# Infinite for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, infinite-loop

```
int i = 0;
double n = 1.24;
    for (; int(n) != n; i++) {
        n *= 10;
    }
```

Why does it enter an infinite loop? Shouldn't it stop after two loops?

Comment: This doesn't compile, `i` isn't declared anywhere

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct it right away.

Answer (score 9):

`1.24` cannot be represented exactly as a `double`. If you examine the initial value of `n`, you'll see that it is `1.239999999999999991118215802998747...`

As to why the loop never stops, once `n` exceeds the value of the largest `double`, it is automatically converted to `+Infinity`, which is a special floating-point value. Once you've reached that point, `n` stops changing and `int(n) != n` can never be satisfied.

Comment: @fpiro07 Because `0.5` *can* be represented exactly (`0.5 == 2^-1`)

Comment: But the debugger actually says that `n` is `1.24`, not `1.239999999...`

Comment: @fpiro07: That's because you're not asking the debugger to print the value to enough significant digits to see this.

Comment: Ok so can I fix it with something like `int(n)-n < EPSILON`?

Comment: @fpiro07: That might work. Whether or not it's a sensible workaround depends on how this code came about, and what you're expecting from it.

Comment: @fpiro07: If you do do this, don't forget to take the absolute value (since `int(n)-n` can be negative as well as positive).

Comment: Ok... Do you maybe have a better solution to my problem? (Transforming `1.24` into `124`, or `3.4213` into `34213` and so on...)

Answer (score 4):

Because double is not exact representation of number and condition int(n) == n never reached.
Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it, and it stops for after two loops. I have used gcc.
I changed int(n) to (int)n

The infinite loop  happens due to some rounding error, try to check the difference between (int)n and n

In general, do not use equally to check equality with double. Use instead

> if (fabs(a-b)<1e-10)  //instead of  a==b

Comment: I seem to be able to reproduce the problem by using a `long double`: http://ideone.com/UrSxGc

Comment: Is `1e-10` equal to `numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`? Or is it better to place `epsilon`?

Comment: you can use arbitrary small value (It is better to have  defined using #define).it should be greater than  numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() because error propagates in calculations. Refer to numerical analysis for more details